# What are Predictive Clustering Trees in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

Anybody could let me know what exactly the PDT is and where does it come from? it comes from predictive modeling or decision tress?

I read some articles and websites like: [this](http://searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/definition/predictive-modeling) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_modelling)
but both of them are about predictive modeling. I think PDT comes from decision tree rather than predictive modeling.

Answer (score 1):

[Clus](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/clus/) might get you started. It uses predictive clustering trees and is described [in this article](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-36755-1_37#page-1), although you'll probably need a student account to get access to that article.

They have a [list of publications](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/clus/publications.html) that you should also find instructive.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I should start from scratch. I think PCTs comes from statistics and I would like to know where I should start to find the idea behind it before using.

Comment: Well the idea behind my response was "read these references", which contain everything you need, especially the list of publications and their references. PCTs are not a beginner topic and you're not going to find a [how-to manual](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).